# What does "composition initiated by an end user" mean?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

The [docs on composition](http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html) state the following:

> In Yeoman, composability can be initiated in two ways:
>
> 1. A generator can decide to compose itself with other generator (e.g., generator-backbone uses generator-mocha).
> 2. An end user may also initiate the composition (e.g., Simon wants to generate a Backbone project with SASS and Rails).

Does anybody have an explanation and an example how the second approach looks like, i.e. how an end user initiates a composition? I understand 1. in so far that when I am writing a generator I can `composeWith()` another generator to reuse the functionality already provided.

*2.* to me sounds like I as user of a generator would also have an opportunity to compose it with something else, but I don't find any indicators if I interpret this right and how it is done.

**Update:**
Looking through the code the only reference to this topic I could find [is here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/base.js#L613). The docstring mentions the following:

```
 * @param  {string} [settings.local]        Path to a locally stored generator
 * @param  {String} [settings.link="weak"]  If "strong", the composition will occured
 *                                          even when the composition is initialized by
 *                                          the end user
```

However, if I am not mistaken the function body neither makes a call to `settings.link` nor passes the `settings` object, so I am not sure if this is actually doing something.

**Update** Added as question/issue on Github
https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/867

Comment: You should post your question update as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status of this feature was clarified in the [github issue](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/867#issuecomment-150809983).

> This is still only a far planned feature.

I will check this as the correct answer, so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered. Whenever such a feature lands feel free to drop a comment so that I can update this.